# Common identifier for a person across disparate systems

Tags: database, mapping, integration, erp

Not sure which is the best Stack Exchange site for this, so will try my hand here.

I have a web application that stores user disciplinary data for organisations.  Rather than clients enter their staff into multiple systems, some want to push the basic personnel data into ours (data such as First Name, Surname, DOB, Job Title etc) from their source (e.g. HR/ERP) databases.

Our clients are using a range of existing systems to store their data, such as Oracle, SAP, JD Edwards, etc.

I am familiar with the technical methods to get this data (e.g. web service, web API), but not for a case such as when a person's surname changes (e.g. Janet Smith gets married and becomes Janet Doe).  Unless there is a unique identifier for that person across both systems, I can't see how that change can be managed reliably.

How is this process best-managed please?  Is an additional field added to the destination database that contains the UID of the source data?  Or, do both parties agree on a common field, e.g. employee number, that never changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue arises in many circumstances. One case is in the **Texas school system where students are tracked longitudinally through numerous education subsystems. A social security number, providing a unique identifier in some cases (although not all) was considered too sensitive for use.** Thus, a unique identifier has been generated for each student and staff member. This is part of the permanent information associated with each individual, regardless of employment change, location change, or name change.

This [link](https://sites.google.com/a/esc14.net/tsds/unique-id) describes the rationale for the unique id.

This [link](http://castro.tea.state.tx.us/tsds/teds/2014A/v2.0/ds9/teds-ds9.pdf) is the documentation on the Texas Student Data System (TSDS) unique identifier. You might find the XML examples at the end of the document of most interest. Much of the information involves submitting requests for an id where demographic information is needed for disambiguation.

Basically, something similar to a Java UUID as an extra field in the database should be sufficient to achieve your aim.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the UID is the only solution. This problem comes up in medical systems too, for example. Another is photos, I'm not sure which causes more problems!

Answer (score 1):

I know approach which is using "external_id" field for that. Several external ids can be exploited in case of many systems.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter as soon as you can convert them between. If you don't want to convert use type of original id for external one.